# Extract a particular substring from filename

Tags: bash, files

The task I need to solve is extract a particular substring from each filename in a directory.

Example file names:

Bob Marley - I Shot The Sheriff-**2XiYUYcpsT4**.mp3
Audioslave - Be Yourself-**WC5FdFlUcl0**.mp3
Bruno Mars - Treasure [Official Music Video]-**nPvuNsRccVw**.mp3

Basically, it is a collection of music I've fetched from youtube and I need to extract the video id (the part in bold).
How can I solve this problem in bash? Splitting based on delimeter is not reliable as the video id sometimes contains an hyphen itself.

Comment: Is it always 11 characters long?

Comment: Yes, as for now. I don't know if changes are planned for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [substring expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for file in ./*.mp3
do
videoid=${file:${#file}-15:11}
printf %s\\n $videoid
done
```

or, if more than one extension, use

```
noext=${file%.*}
videoid=${noext:${#noext}-11:11}
```

This assumes that [youtube video IDs are always 11 characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13854).

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Your provided solution works for every file in my directory.

Answer (score 2):

If there's always a dash before the id, and there's no dash after the id, you can use simple parameter expansion. `%` removes the pattern from the end of the value, `#` from the beginning. Doubling the symbol makes it "greedy" - it removes as much as it can.

```
#! /bin/bash

files=( 'Bob Marley - I Shot The Sheriff-2XiYUYcpsT4.mp3'
        'Audioslave - Be Yourself-WC5FdFlUcl0.mp3'
        'Bruno Mars - Treasure [Official Music Video]-nPvuNsRccVw.mp3'
      )

for file in "${files[@]}" ; do
    id=${file##*-}
    id=${id%.mp3}
    echo "$id"
done
```

Comment: I need to extract the video id (as to do other operations with it), not remove it.

Comment: @tholgard: Ah, OK, updated.